# How do i get the current text of a QCombobox edited?

Tags: c++, qt

i want get the current text of a QComboBox edited.

```
QString nome = ui->taxas_existentes->currentText();
```

I have this, but if the initial text was "Test" and i change to "Test1", the variable "nome" will have "Test" as value instead of "Test1"...

Edit:

I've this, then i click on icon of edit

[image]

I change the name "Teste" to "Teste1" and i click on green icone

[image]

Then, after i clicked on green icone, i have this code:

```
QString nome = ui->taxas_existentes->currentText();
```

The variable nome have a value of "Teste" instead of "Teste1"...

edit2:

```
        void WidgetDefinicoes::on_editar_taxa_clicked()
    {
        GereTaxa gereTaxas = GereTaxa();
        if(ui->taxas_existentes->isEditable()) {
            ui->taxas_existentes->setEditable(false);

            QString nome = ui->taxas_existentes->currentText();

            if(!nome.isEmpty()){

                    GereTaxa gereTaxa = GereTaxa();
                    int idTaxa = gereTaxas.obtemId(taxas.at(0)->getNome());
                    if(nome == taxas.at(0)->getNome()) {
                        Taxa * taxa = new Taxa(idTaxa, taxaInt, nome);
                        qDebug() << taxa->getTaxa();
                        qDebug() << taxa->getNome();

                        if(gereTaxa.editTaxa(* taxa) == 1) {
                           QMessageBox::information(this,tr("SalesQ"),tr("A taxa foi alterada com sucesso!"));
                        } else {
                           QMessageBox::warning(this,tr("SalesQ"),tr("Ocorreu um erro a alterar a taxa!"));
                        }
                   }
          }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a _minimal, complete and reproducible_ example of your issue ? Because getting the text of the current item of a `QComboBox` after changing it works fine.

Comment: Done... I've put more images on edit

Comment: Images are not a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See now... Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error!

```
ui->taxas_existentes->setEditable(false);
```

Must be after of

```
QString nome = ui->taxas_existentes->currentText();
```

And not before